# Can't Change screenshot while app is waiting for review?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted app on ituneconnect. 
it is currently waiting for review state
and now i want to change screenshot of my app.

as per my google searching we can change screen shot of app in waiting for review state.

but I didn't see edit image option there?

appreciate for help

Comment: Same here my In-app not working for sandbox account.

Comment: The same issue occur in my case.

Comment: I have same issue, and I'm sure this not happening few weeks ago. I think its obviously Apple lock screen metadata after "Submit for review" button pressed. Yet the deceiving information box said "You can edit all information while your version is waiting for review.". I have one of my app changed status to "Ready for sale" with old screenshot in it..

Answer (score 8):

As of July 2020, it is no longer possible to change the screenshots when in "Waiting for Review" state. However this is a workaround:

There is the message that says:

> You can edit all information while your version is waiting for review.
> To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review.

This is not true. I have clicked on `remove this version from review.`, changed the screenshots, and clicked on `Submit for Review` again and it was accepted. I did NOT have to upload a new build.

However it is hard to say if I lost my place in the review queue or not. At least I didn't have to recompile and wait for an hour before I could re-submit it again.

Answer (score 4):

Now you can change the screenshots in the "Waiting For Review" state again. Here is an updated list from the FAQ pages at iTunes Connect (2016-09-12) of what you can do in different states:

> **What changes can I make to the current app version I've submitted?**
>
> You can always edit the following information:
>
> • Copyright
> • Description
> • EULA
> • Marketing URL
> • Pricing
> • Contact Email Address
> • Support URL
> • Privacy Policy URL
> • Release Notes
>
> You can only edit the following information if your app is in an
> editable state:
>
> • Categories
> • Keywords
> • Large Icon
> • Localization Addition or deletion
> • App Name
> • Ratings
> • Review Notes
> • Screenshot
> • Version Number
> • Version Release
>
> Editable states are:
>
> • Prepare For Submission
> • Waiting For Review
> • Waiting For Export Compliance
> • Rejected
> • Metadata Rejected
> • Developer Rejected

Answer (score 4):

Even though apple showing that you can change all during 'waiting for review' you can't (6th July 2020). I have 'removed the version from review and changed the screenshots and resubmitted without uploading new build.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the `In app screenshots` when your app is waiting for review . Apple has `"Locked"` that field. [Mentioned in iTunes Developer guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

**It is possible to change app information including screenshot while waiting for for review.**

[image]

But if you want to change the build, you need to cancel the review and submit again with new build.

Comment: That is not valid anymore. Today you cannot do that

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, now it is NOT possible to change the screenshots when in "Waiting for Review" state again.